# Why does one of these sorting criterias work, but not the other?

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working  on a part of a program that sorts posts in an array by several criteria. The posts are sorted just fine until the program gets to the last block of code.

This block of code sorts the posts as it should:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) 
    for (j = i + 1; j < 12; j++)
        if (serie[j].poang == serie[i].poang)
            if ((serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta) < (serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta))
            {
                temp.poang = serie[i].poang;
                serie[i].poang = serie[j].poang;
                serie[j].poang = temp.poang;

                temp.gjorda = serie[i].gjorda;
                serie[i].gjorda = serie[j].gjorda;
                serie[j].gjorda = temp.gjorda;

                temp.inslappta = serie[i].inslappta;
                serie[i].inslappta = serie[j].inslappta;
                serie[j].inslappta = temp.inslappta;

                strcpy(temp.namn, serie[i].namn);
                strcpy(serie[i].namn, serie[j].namn);
                strcpy(serie[j].namn, temp.namn);
            }
```

While this one doesn't seem to affect the sorting at all (I even tried reversing the "<" sign in the last "if" statement in the code below, but it doesn't change the sorting at all, leading me to believe something is off with the whole block):

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    for (j = i + 1; j < 12; j++)
        if (serie[j].poang == serie[i].poang)
            if ((serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta) < (serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta))
                if(serie[j].gjorda < serie[i].gjorda)
                {
                    temp.poang = serie[i].poang;
                    serie[i].poang = serie[j].poang;
                    serie[j].poang = temp.poang;

                    temp.gjorda = serie[i].gjorda;
                    serie[i].gjorda = serie[j].gjorda;
                    serie[j].gjorda = temp.gjorda;

                    temp.inslappta = serie[i].inslappta;
                    serie[i].inslappta = serie[j].inslappta;
                    serie[j].inslappta = temp.inslappta;

                    strcpy(temp.namn, serie[i].namn);
                    strcpy(serie[i].namn, serie[j].namn);
                    strcpy(serie[j].namn, temp.namn);
                }
```

Comment: Are either subtractions like `serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta` and `serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta` subject to overflow?

Comment: You should show the structure definition.  It might matter how the `namn` member is defined.  If might be an array (`char namn[30];`) or a pointer (`char *namn;`) or you might have been inventive and done something else.  With pointers, you have to worry about storage space; with arrays you don't.  You should look at whether you can use structure assignment, too.

Comment: The swap is complicated.  Suggest `temp = serie[i]; serie[i] = serie[j]; serie[j] = temp;`.

Comment: You're applying different sorting criteria, so the result might well be different.  The leading equality condition is unusual.  It means that if the `poang` elements of the compared records are different, then those records never need to be swapped; they're already in sorted order.  Maybe you should show some sample data, and the actual and expected results?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — while you've minimized the code, you've not provided a complete example, nor have you shown the data.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in `qsort()` function?

Comment: @chux The numbers processed are not very big, so I wouldn't think so. Also your swapping looks way more neat, but I prefer keeping the program as I've written it as much as I can. I'll keep it in mind for the future though :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The struct definition can be found here: https://justpaste.it/15o40

The program is not very long, so here is the source code for it in its entirety if someone is interested: https://justpaste.it/15o49

Comment: What is the sorting criterion you're trying to implement?  You need to be able to state it in words before you can implement it.  I think at the moment you aren't implementing what you want, but without the description and the sample data, it's hard to be sure.  Also, the structure definition is tiny — it should be added to the question.  (I can't do it because I reviewed my full quota of suggested edits so I'm hamstrung until midnight UTC.)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
if (serie[j].poang == serie[i].poang)
    if ((serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta) < (serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta))
        if(serie[j].gjorda < serie[i].gjorda)
```

And then swap, you are effectively saying the && of all of those conditions determines orders, which seems wrong to me.

I would make a function `isInOrder` that takes the array pointer and the two indexes and returns TRUE if the left one is before the right one.  Then

```
if (!isInOrder(serie, i, j)) {
     // swap
}
```

Your function is (with the type of serie as `S*`):

```
int isInOrder(S *array, int i, int j) {
    // fill this in. Return 1 if they are in order, 0 if not
}
```

The main issue with your original if is that you don't specify an order for when .poang is not equal.  If your original array has .poang with all different values, then the order would never change.

Comment: Could you rephrase "you are effectively saying the && of all of those conditions"? I'm not sure what to make of that

Comment: @JakobEklund: the swap only happens if (1) `(serie[j].poang == serie[i].poang)` _and_ (2) `((serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta) < (serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta))` _and_ (3) `(serie[j].gjorda < serie[i].gjorda)`.  If any one of those conditions is false, no swap.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh I see where I went wrong now, that solved it. Thanks everyone who commented!